# Существует ли ALTER TABLE с указанием конкретной базы данных?

Tags: mysql

Имеется запрос

```
ALTER TABLE jos_md_catalog_model MODIFY {"label":null,"type":null,"lookup_table":"jos_md_catalog_year","lookup_nameas":null,"lookup_idas":null,"lookup_filter":null} COMMENT '';
```

Если в строке коннекта указана база, то все прекрасно работает.
Если не указана то соответственно вылетает `No Select Database`.
Все другие запросы я доработал с указанием конкретной базы, с использованием ключевых фраз типа FROM, IN.
А с этим запросом что то не нашел такого варианта.

Comment: а таблицу  указанием имени БД не пробовали, типа `alter table db_name.table_name ...`

Comment: начинает ругаться. `{"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{""label"":null,""type"":null,""lookup_table"":""jos_md_catalog_year"",""lookup_nameas"":n' at line 1"}`

Comment: У вас ошибка в синтаксисе ALTER TABLE после MODIFY вы можете указать лишь один столбец, без фигурных скобок и в формате принятом в MySQL без двоеточия. Если нужно поменять несколько столбцов, нужно через запятую указать несколько MODIFY выражений. Такое ощущение, что у вас после MODIFY идет просто хэш, не приведенный к формату MySQL.

Comment: вы ошибаетесь, нет там ошибок, там текст JSON и суть вопроса описана выше.

Comment: Что-то я не вижу JSON в MODIFY: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: В комментарий можно записать любой текст, и там у меня записаны параметры для поля в виде JSON! И сам вопрос никакого отношения к этому не имеет, вопрос в том как указать базу конкретную где мы модифицируем таблицу.